# Prevent Electron App from attaching to console window

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I created an Electron App (packed with: electron-builder + nsis-web installer) on Windows.

The App works fine, but i want to open the app from a console window (cmd or powershell).
Unfortunately, the app is then attached to the console window.
When the console window is closed, the app is also closed.
The problem does not occur if I use the portable-nsis option.

Any way to prevent this?

[image: Image Task Manager]

Comment: How is the NSIS tag relevant?

Comment: Maybe it's an NSIS problem? If I use other options (portable etc) it works as intended. (without the console attach)

Comment: NSIS is not a console program so NSIS cannot cause console connection issues.